# How to edit a localized Webflow CMS collection

Tags: locale, webflow

I have localized our Webflow site with EN (default) and FR. I need to regularly update the content of a CMS Collection by way of a Make automation for both EN & FR locale. The problem is that a CMS collection has a single ID for both locales. It is of paramount importance to be able to modify the content of CMS collection items programmatically. Thanks for any ressource or/and assistance in that regards.

Using the Webflow UI, it is possible to modify the content of a CMS content after selecting a  locale, but the API does not apparently differentiate the locales of a CMS collection.